# No performance improvement with multiple consumer

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to consume messages from rabbit mq using multiple consumers.

For my basic use case: We have 50K messages in the queue and each consumer reads one message from the queue and executes an algo with 50 DB query and then sends ack to rabbit mq.

My problem is ack per sec remains constant for 5 consumers, 10 consumers, 20 consumers i.e. 11 Ack/sec.

I have tried commenting my insert queries in algo. So I think there is no locking issue in the code.

```
    public void init() {
        try {
            factory.setUri(System.getenv("CLOUDAMQP_URL"));
            connection = factory.newConnection();
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
                | URISyntaxException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void processJobInstance() {
        for (int i = 0; i < batchJobInstanceList.size(); i++) {

                for (int c = 0; c < NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS_PER_JOB; c++) {
                    try {
                        /*
                         * Do not close channel here as doWork is a future task. We will close channel in handle
                         * delivery.
                         */
                        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                        final Consumer consumer = createConsumerBean(channel, batchJobInstance.getId());
        boolean autoAck = false;
        channel.basicQos(1);
        channel.basicConsume(batchJobInstance.getId(), autoAck, consumer);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Channel failed by Exception.", e);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

        @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Consumer createConsumerBean(Channel channel, final String id) {
        return new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                    byte[] body) throws IOException {

                try {
// Algo with 50 select calls and 5-10 insert                

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.error("HandleDelivery failed by Exception.", ex);
                } finally {
                    channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleCancel(String consumerTag) throws IOException {
                log.info("Cancelled: " + consumerTag);
            }
        };
    }
```

What is wrong with my code that increasing number of consumer is not improving performance?

Comment: Have you tried checking what call takes how much time? I would guess the DB is a bottleneck since it's definitely synchronized across all consumers.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is on the database side?

Comment: @n1t4chi my guess is also db but how I can confirm that db calls are synchronized across all consumers.

Comment: @MoneyParashar Usually DBs have synchronized writes when saving the similar tables since otherwise would easily lead to corrupted data where two querries are saving to the same row at the same time. Also reads are synchronized when writing is done at the same time. PostgreSQL definitely uses transactions for queries which are synchronized.

Comment: @n1t4chi I agree with you but I have also tried commenting insert queries and ack/sec remains the same. I think there is some issue with select queries also.

Comment: @MoneyParashar Then maybe comment all DB operations and check the time then? You can also try using JVisualVM to check what operation takes the most time in each thread. This way you don't need to guess what is the problem.

Comment: @n1t4chi After commenting all DB operations performance improved. So it is definite that issue is at DB level.

Comment: Multiple consumers on the same hardware does not always give you better performance, even when there are no bottlenecks. If your process only has access to 4 CPU cores, then running 8 threads will not be any faster than running 4. In fact, might be *slower* since you have twice the context switching overhead. When you are performance tuning, make sure you are tuning the right thing.